# Survey123 Summary Report syntax with dates

Tags: arcgis-online, reports, arcgis-survey123, summary

I'm working on a summary report for pump station inspections.  I'm using a repeat tag to fill out the table which will insert a row for each pump station with it's summed inspection data.  I was able to get the syntax correct to sum the data for each question for each individual pump station.  But I'm struggling with how to show the most recent inspection date for each pump station.

You'll see in my syntax I tried to use `stats: max,REPDATE,InsDate` but that gives me the most recent inspection date of ALL the inspections.  I only want the most recent inspection date per pump station. I've tried shifting things around, but I keep getting errors and when I don't get an error I get the most recent date overall.

I inserted what I have so far for the report template table below.

$<$Summary>

| Station No. | Last Inspection Date | Pump 1 Run Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ${#PumpStationLogs | stats:"count,FACILITYID; **max,REPDATE,InsDate**; sum,P1_RNHrs,SumP1; sum,P2_RNHrs,SumP2; sum,BIOXIDE,SumBiox; sum,GENERATOR,SumGen; sum, ELCTMTR_R18,Electric; sum, H2OMTR_R18,SumWater":"PSNAME": "" | where:"1=1" | orderByFields:"PSNAME ASC" }${PSNAME} | **${InsDate | format:"DD"}** | ${SumP|round:2} |

$</>